# How can I validate any PDF has a signature

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have to check whether a PDF has a signature (handling contracts) and need a way of verifying this.

I've read some stuff about certificates for signing the PDF, but wasn't sure if that was something separate.

Or checking the metadata on a PDF.

Whats the most efficient way to check for a signature in node?

Comment: Please indicate first what kinds of signatures you want to recognize: Do you only mean digital signatures (i.e. signatures backed by cryptographic algorithms and public/private key pairs) or arbitrary electronic signatures (also including mere images of a signature stroke)?

Comment: Image of a signature stroke

Comment: *"Image of a signature stroke"* - that's clearly non-trivial. Signature strokes can be added to a PDF in numerous ways, and these ways also allow to add non-signature strokes or images. Thus, is there anything peculiar about your signatures to distinguish them from arbitrary scribbles and images?

Comment: There isn't anything peculiar, we just want a signature on the pdf. We trust the sender, just dont want to manually view a signature is there each time

Comment: That makes it really hard. I've no idea. Maybe some AI, some neural network trained to recognize signatures...?

Comment: What would a decent approach be for verifying a pdf by verifying their pdf with public key?

Comment: Public key digital signatures integrated in PDFs are easy to find. Apoorva Chikara's answer appears to show an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@ninja-labs/verify-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ninja-labs/verify-pdf) and do something like this:

```
const verifyPDF = require('@ninja-labs/verify-pdf');
const signedPdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync('yourPdf');

const {
    verified,
    authenticity,
    integrity,
    expired,
    meta
} = verifyPDF(signedPdfBuffer);
```